# Logging current function name

Tags: r, function, logging

I have a few custom logfunctions that are extensions of `cat`. A basic example is something like this:

```
catt<-function(..., file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL,
    append = FALSE)
{
    cat(..., format(Sys.time(), "(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)"), "\n", file = file, 
        sep = sep, fill = fill, labels = labels, append = append)
}
```

Now, I work a lot with (selfmade) functions, and use some of these logfuntions to see the progress, which works quite well. What I notice, though, is that I almost always use these functions like this:

```
somefunc<-function(blabla)
{
  catt("somefunc: start")
  #do some very useful stuff here
  catt("somefunc: some time later")
  #even more useful stuff
  catt("somefunc: the end")
}
```

Notice how every call to `catt` begins with the name of the function it is called from. Very neat until I start to refactor my code and rename functions etc.

Thanks to some old R-list post from Brian Ripley, if I'm not mistaken, I found this code to get the 'current function name':

```
catw<-function(..., file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL,
    append = FALSE)
{
    curcall<-sys.call(sys.parent(n=1))
    prefix<-paste(match.call(call=curcall)[[1]], ":", sep="")
    cat(prefix, ..., format(Sys.time(), "(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)"), "\n",
        file = file, sep = sep, fill = fill, labels = labels, append = append)
}
```

This is very nice, but it doesn't always work, because:

- my functions are scattered with anonymous functions used in `lapply`
  type of functions, like this:

> ```
> aFunc<-function(somedataframe)
> {
>   result<-lapply(seq_along(somedataframe), function(i){
>   catw("working on col", i, "/", ncol(somedataframe))
>   #do some more stuff here and return something
>   return(sum(is.na(somedataframe[[i]])))
>   }
> }
> ```

-> for these cases, apparently (and understandably) I need n=3 in the `sys.parent` call in my `catw` function.

- I occasionally use `do.call`: it appears my current implementation
  doesn't work either (once again I can somewhat understand it, though
  I haven't figured it out completely.

So, my question is: is there a way to find the first *named* function higher in the callstack (skipping the logging function itself, and maybe some other "wellknown" exceptions), which would allow me to write one single version of `catw` for all cases (so that I can happily refactor without worrying about my logging code)? How would you go about something like this?

**Edit**: these cases should be supported:

```
testa<-function(par1)
{
    catw("Hello from testa, par1=", par1)
    for(i in 1:2) catw("normal loop from testa, item", i)
    rv<-sapply(1:2, function(i){catw("sapply from testa, item", i);return(i)})
    return(rv)
}

testb<-function(par1, par2)
{
    catw("Hello from testb, par1=", par1)
    for(i in 1:2) catw("normal loop from testb, item", i)
    rv<-sapply(1:2, function(i){catw("sapply from testb, item", i);return(i)})

    catw("Will now call testa from testb")
    rv2<-testa(par1)
    catw("Back from testa call in testb")

    catw("Will now do.call testa from testb")
    rv2<-do.call(testa, list(par1))
    catw("Back from testa do.call in testb")

    return(list(rv, rv2))
}

testa(123)
testb(123,456)
do.call(testb, list(123,456))
```

Comment: I frequently use `message()` in my functions to output a note to the console to tell me what what point R is at in the function. Perhaps, some implementation of message() and sink(...,type="message") would work for you? Downside is that you'd have to put it in all of your functions.

Comment: Could a grep applied to the sys.call work, assuming you use a unique naming scheme for your functions?  Selecting the first match should be the lowest in the set.

Comment: @Iterator: a naming scheme for functions is not an option right now. But I am willing to live with the opposite: excluding certain schemes (like ".*apply.*").

Comment: @Nick.  I erred.  I use a naming scheme, but any list (okay, vector of character strings) of names that is unique to your set (package) should be adequate.  Getting the list of base R functions (or maybe all functions when all nec. libraries are loaded) and running `setdiff()` should lead to such a list, if you prefer not to do it manually or don't have access to the namespace.  Someone more familiar with R than I would know how to get this list.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT : Complete rewrite of function**

The new version of this function uses the call stack, `sys.calls()`, rather than `match.call`.

The call stack contains the complete calling function.  So the trick now is to only extract the bits of it that you really want.  I have resorted to a bit of manual cleanup in the `clean_cs` function.  This evaluates the first word in the call stack and returns the desired argument for a small number of known edge cases, in particular `lapply`, `sapply` and `do.call`.

The only downside of this approach is that it will return function names all the way to the top of the call stack.  Perhaps a logical next step would be to compare these functions with a spefified environment/namespace and include/exclude function names based on that...

I shall stop here.  It answers to the use cases in the question.

---

The new function:

```
catw <- function(..., callstack=sys.calls()){
  cs <- callstack
  cs <- clean_cs(cs)
  #browser()
  message(paste(cs, ...))
}

clean_cs <- function(x){
  val <- sapply(x, function(xt){
    z <- strsplit(paste(xt, collapse="\t"), "\t")[[1]]
    switch(z[1],
        "lapply" = z[3], 
        "sapply" = z[3],
        "do.call" = z[2], 
        "function" = "FUN",
        "source" = "###",
        "eval.with.vis" = "###",
        z[1]
        )
    })
  val[grepl("\\<function\\>", val)] <- "FUN"
  val <- val[!grepl("(###|FUN)", val)]
  val <- head(val, -1)
  paste(val, collapse="|")
}
```

---

Test results:

```
testa Hello from testa, par1= 123
testa normal loop from testa, item 1
testa normal loop from testa, item 2
testa sapply from testa, item 1
testa sapply from testa, item 2


testb Hello from testb, par1= 123
testb normal loop from testb, item 1
testb normal loop from testb, item 2
testb sapply from testb, item 1
testb sapply from testb, item 2
testb Will now call testa from testb
testb|testa Hello from testa, par1= 123
testb|testa normal loop from testa, item 1
testb|testa normal loop from testa, item 2
testb|testa sapply from testa, item 1
testb|testa sapply from testa, item 2
testb Back from testa call in testb
testb Will now do.call testa from testb
testb|testa Hello from testa, par1= 123
testb|testa normal loop from testa, item 1
testb|testa normal loop from testa, item 2
testb|testa sapply from testa, item 1
testb|testa sapply from testa, item 2
testb Back from testa do.call in testb


testb Hello from testb, par1= 123
testb normal loop from testb, item 1
testb normal loop from testb, item 2
testb sapply from testb, item 1
testb sapply from testb, item 2
testb Will now call testa from testb
testb|testa Hello from testa, par1= 123
testb|testa normal loop from testa, item 1
testb|testa normal loop from testa, item 2
testb|testa sapply from testa, item 1
testb|testa sapply from testa, item 2
testb Back from testa call in testb
testb Will now do.call testa from testb
testb|testa Hello from testa, par1= 123
testb|testa normal loop from testa, item 1
testb|testa normal loop from testa, item 2
testb|testa sapply from testa, item 1
testb|testa sapply from testa, item 2
testb Back from testa do.call in testb
```

Comment: what if my function holds nested `sapply` calls with anonymous functions (admitted, it's somewhat contrived). Your choice of `nLevels<-3` will not cover that, right? I'm trying to use `sys.parents()` to avoid that, but I'm a bit stumped on when I need to add numbers to this (or how many), e.g. when I call this outside your `sapply` call. The docs are _very_ terse on calls and stackframes.

Comment: @NickSabbe, In my edited version I use `sys.nframe` to get the call stack depth, rather than specifying a fixed `nlevels`.  I also use `grep` to remove `apply`, `lapply`, `sapply` and family.

Comment: Nearly there. I've got one more (nasty) challenge, though: what if I immediately call `do.call(my.col, list(df))` ? This happens to me quite often, as I tend to save parameters to functions in lists during debugging, so I can easily (re)call them. In this case there is something strange happening, because now the result of  `sys.call(sys.parent(n=i))[[1]]` appears to be a function (closure), but does not hold the name of the original function anymore :-(

Comment: @NickSabbe Nice challenge, but it defeated me.  Answer edited with best effort.

Comment: @NickSabbe Answer edited once more with a completely new approach.

Comment: can you say "king of the hill" ?

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd add the progress made so far, based *completely* on Andrie's work. Pretty sure other people will enjoy this, so it is now a part of a package I'm developing (not on `CRAN` but on `R-Forge` for now) called `addendum` (including documentation) after the nightly build.

Function to find the 'current lowest named function' on the callstack with some bells and whistles:

```
curfnfinder<-function(skipframes=0, skipnames="(FUN)|(.+apply)|(replicate)",
    retIfNone="Not in function", retStack=FALSE, extraPrefPerLevel="\t")
{
    prefix<-sapply(3 + skipframes+1:sys.nframe(), function(i){
            currv<-sys.call(sys.parent(n=i))[[1]]
            return(currv)
        })
    prefix[grep(skipnames, prefix)] <- NULL
    prefix<-gsub("function \\(.*", "do.call", prefix)
    if(length(prefix)==0)
    {
        return(retIfNone)
    }
    else if(retStack)
    {
        return(paste(rev(prefix), collapse = "|"))
    }
    else
    {
        retval<-as.character(unlist(prefix[1]))
        if(length(prefix) > 1)
        {
            retval<-paste(paste(rep(extraPrefPerLevel, length(prefix) - 1), collapse=""), retval, sep="")
        }
        return(retval)
    }
}
```

This can be used in a logging function like this:

```
catw<-function(..., file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL,
    append = FALSE, prefix=0)
{
    if(is.numeric(prefix))
    {
        prefix<-curfnfinder(skipframes=prefix+1) #note: the +1 is there to avoid returning catw itself
        prefix<-paste(prefix, ":", sep="")
    }
    cat(prefix, ..., format(Sys.time(), "(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)"), "\n",
        file = file, sep = sep, fill = fill, labels = labels, append = append)
}
```

As mentioned in the comments to Andrie's answer so far, there are still some issues regarding `do.call`. I'm going to stop spending time on it for now, but have posted the related question on the [r-devel mailinglist](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-September/061931.html). If/when I get a response there, and it is usable, I will update the functions.

Comment: Hey @Nick, is `addendum` still alive? I can't find it anywhere, nor can I find this function anywhere else (http://search.r-project.org/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=curfnfinder&idxname=functions). If `addendum` is archived, would you be ok with me adding this function to `userfriendlyscience`, crediting you as author of course?